# How can I add an infinite scrolling in my MUI DataGrid keeping the DataGrid? I don't want to use a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Basically, I have this component and I have to add it an **infinite scrolling**. I've read MUI **DataGrid** but couldn't apply anything successfully. I'm using **GraphQL to fetch the data** and i was using arrows to move to the next page but I have removed them. I'm fetching 100 styles on each page. Could anyone help me?
I couldn't find any way to pass the fetchMore function that useLazyQuery has and that it works.
I'm always stuck in displaying like the first page and the first 100 styles.

This is the component:

```
return (
    <>
      <StyledForm sx={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 72px)', p: 0, pt: 0, position: 'relative' }}>
        <DataGrid
          rows={tableRows}
          columns={columns}
          loading={isStylesLoading || !tableRows}
          localeText={localeText}
          rowCount={totalCount}
          getRowClassName={(params: GridRowParams): string => {
                const isPinnedRow = params.row.id.includes('pinned');
                return `${classes.row} ${isPinnedRow ? classes.pinnedRow : ''}`;
          }}
          rowHeight={64}
          paginationMode="server"
          pageSize={size}
          classes={{
                root: classes.root,
                columnHeaders: classes.columnHeaders,
                columnHeaderTitle: classes.columnHeaderTitle,
                cell: classes.cell,
                columnSeparator: classes.columnSeparator,
                footerContainer: classes.footerContainer,
          }}
          components={{
                LoadingOverlay,
                // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unstable-nested-components
                Pagination: () => null,
          }}
          componentsProps={{
                row: {
                  onMouseEnter: handleRowMouseEnter,
                  onMouseLeave: handleRowMouseLeave,
                },
          }}
          disableSelectionOnClick
          disableColumnMenu
          onCellClick={handleCellClick}
        />
      </StyledForm>
      <StyleDialogDrawer isEdit={isEdit} />
    </>
  );
};
```

but my Query is in a different file in the same project:

```
const size = 100;

const totalCountReducer = (state, action): number => {
  if (action.type === 'update_totalCount') {
    microFrontendsUtil.sendMessage(
      APPLICATION_NAMES.styles,
      APPLICATION_NAMES.umbrella,
      {
        topic: TopicTokens.resultsAmount,
        action: ActionTokens.resultsAmount.update,
        payload: {
          resultsAmount: action.newTotalCount,
        },
      }
    );
    return action.newTotalCount;
  }
  return state;
};

interface PropTypes {
  children: ReactNode;
}


export const StylesHOC = ({ children }: PropTypes): ReactElement => {
  const datadogRum = useContext(DataDogRumContext);
  const { pinnedStyles } = useContext(PinnedStylesContext);
  const { searchQuery }: { searchQuery: string } = useSearchBar();
  const { selectedBrands } = useSelectedBrands();
  const { collectionsFilter } = useCollectionsFilter();
  const { productLinesFilter } = useProductLinesFilter();
  const { purchaseDivisionsFilter } = usePurchaseDivisionsFilter();

  const [totalCount, totalCountDispatch] = useReducer(totalCountReducer, 0);
  const [styles, setStyles] = useState<Array<Partial<Style>>>([]);
  const [cursors, setCursors] = useState<Array<CursorObject>>([{ pageIndex: 0, cursor: '' }]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState<number>(0);

  const [getStyles, { loading: getStylesQueryLoading, error: getStylesQueryError }] = useLazyQuery(
    graphQlService.getAllStyles,
    {
      variables: {
        brandNumber: selectedBrands[0],
        collectionNumber: collectionsFilter?.collectionNumber,
        productLineNumber: productLinesFilter?.productLineNumber,
        purchaseDivisionNumber: purchaseDivisionsFilter?.purchaseDivisionNumber,
        generalQuery: searchQuery,
        pagination: {
          first: size,
          after: cursors.find((c) => c.pageIndex === page)?.cursor ?? '',
        },
      },
      pollInterval: 0,
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      context: { clientName: GraphClientNames['blabla'] },
      onCompleted: (data) => {
        const newCursor = data.styles?.edges.at(-1)?.cursor;
        if (!cursors.map((c) => c.cursor).includes(newCursor)) {
          const newCursors = cursors.slice();
          newCursors.push({ pageIndex: page + 1, cursor: newCursor });
          setCursors(newCursors);
        }
        totalCountDispatch({ type: 'update_totalCount', newTotalCount: data.styles?.totalCount ?? 0 });
        setStyles(
          data.styles?.edges
            .map((edge) => edge.node)
            .filter((node) => !pinnedStyles.includes(node.styleNumber)) || []
        );
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        snackbarUtility.showErrorSnackbar('Could not load styles!', error.message, APPLICATION_NAMES.styles);
        console.error(error);
        datadogRum?.addError(error);
      },
    }
  );

  const updateStyles = useMemo(() => (style: Partial<Style>): void => {
    // If we have a style with the same styleNumber, update it, otherwise keep the old styles
    const newStyles = styles.map((s) => s.styleNumber === style.styleNumber ? { ...s, ...style } : s);
    setStyles(newStyles);
  }, [styles]);

  const contextValue = useMemo(
    () => ({
      styles,
      isStylesLoading: getStylesQueryLoading,
      stylesError: getStylesQueryError,
      totalCount,
      cursors,
      size,
      page,
      setPage,
      updateStyles,
    }),
    [cursors, getStylesQueryError, getStylesQueryLoading, page, styles, totalCount, updateStyles]
  );

  // NOTE: Reset table on changes (unless style card is open)
  useEffect(() => {
    setPage(0);
    setCursors([{ pageIndex: 0, cursor: '' }]);
    if (selectedBrands.length !== 0) {
      getStyles();
    }
  }, [selectedBrands, searchQuery, getStyles]);

  return <StylesContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</StylesContext.Provider>;
};
```